# Position Image in Bottom Center Of Page CSS

Tags: html, css, positioning, center

I'm sure there is a certain way to position an image at the bottom of the page center in CSS with a little white space, but I haven't been able to find an effective method yet. What are yall's suggestions?

Comment: Can you show what code you have got so far in attempting to do this?

Comment: Let the image be in normal flow (at the end of the page) and give `display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;` to it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do it -

HTML:

```
<img class="my-img" width="200" src="/path/to/image.jpg" />
```

CSS:

```
.my-img {
    position    : absolute;
    bottom      : 10px;
    left        : 50%;
    margin-left : -100px; /* half width of img */
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/q3e6qmdq/

Comment: Doesn't this keep the image at the bottom of viewport (rather than the page)? If this meets the OP's needs, the question itself is misleading.

Comment: Uhoh. Sorry about that. Yea... it would.